# Allow a stored procedure to decrypt an encrypted column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, symmetric-key

I created a symmetric key in SQL Server 2016 and then encrypted a single column in the table (`PhoneNo`).

If I run the following code, the column is decrypted and displays the result:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Test DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test;

SELECT        
    ClientContactTest.ClientID, ClientContactTest.ContactID, 
    ClientContactTest.Title, ClientContactTest.Forename, 
    ClientContactTest.Surname, 
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(ClientContactTest.PhoneNo_Encrypt)) AS PhoneNo,  
    ClientContactTest.MobileNo, ClientContactTest.EMailAddress, 
    Lookup_ContactType.Description AS ContactTypeDescription
FROM
    ClientContactTest 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Lookup_ContactType ON ClientContactTest.ContactTypeID = Lookup_ContactType.ContactTypeID
WHERE
    (ClientContactTest.ClientID = 7) 
    AND (ClientContactTest.SiteID = 0) 
    AND (ClientContactTest.ContactID = 1)

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Test
```

BUT if I put the exact same code inside a stored procedure it returns NULL for this column:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClientContactTest_LoadRecord_Encrypted]
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Test DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test;

    SELECT        
        ClientContactTest.ClientID, ClientContactTest.ContactID, 
        ClientContactTest.Title, ClientContactTest.Forename, 
        ClientContactTest.Surname, 
        CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(ClientContactTest.PhoneNo_Encrypt)) AS PhoneNo, 
        ClientContactTest.MobileNo, ClientContactTest.EMailAddress, 
        Lookup_ContactType.Description AS ContactTypeDescription
    FROM
        ClientContactTest 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Lookup_ContactType ON ClientContactTest.ContactTypeID = Lookup_ContactType.ContactTypeID
    WHERE
        (ClientContactTest.ClientID = 7) 
        AND (ClientContactTest.SiteID = 0) 
        AND (ClientContactTest.ContactID = 1)

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Test
END
```

The stored procedure has execute permission to a role called `CRMObjects`.

How do I get the correct result returned?

Tried the following steps, but those made no difference:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE :: Certificate_Test TO CRMObjects;
GRANT CONTROL ON SYMMETRIC KEY :: SymKey_Test TO CRMObjects

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::SymKey_Test TO CRMObjects
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON Certificate::[Certificate_Test] TO CRMObjects
```

Comment: Could just be the typo in the key/certificate names while you granting permissions?

Comment: You can use the functions DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT or DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY that facilitates the management of keys...

Comment: FAB - Sorry about the typo I did notice that after typing and makes no difference.

Comment: SQLpro - I did try both these methods and getting NULL value so decided to start again by removing all Certificates & keys. It now works !!
Thank you both FAB & SQLpro for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally solve this so thought it a good idea to post what I eventually did

-- Create Master Key, Certificate & Symetric Key

```
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mzkvdlk979438teag$$ds987yghn)(*&4fdg^';  
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mzkvdlk979438teag$$ds987yghn)(*&4fdg^';  
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2 WITH SUBJECT = 'Test 2'  
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 WITH ALGORITHM = DES ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2;  
GO  


-- Open Key, Encrypt Field & Close Key

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2 ;  
UPDATE ClientContactTest  
SET PhoneNo_Encrypt  
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), PhoneNo);  
GO  
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01;
```

-- And Test It

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2;
SELECT        CONVERT(varchar(20), DecryptByKey(ClientContactTest.PhoneNo_Encrypt)) AS PhoneNo 
FROM            ClientContactTest
WHERE        (ClientContactTest.ClientID = 7)
```

-- Create Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClientContact_LoadRecord_Encrypted] 
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2;
    SELECT        CONVERT(varchar(20), DecryptByKey(ClientContactTest.PhoneNo_Encrypt)) AS PhoneNo 
    FROM            ClientContactTest
    WHERE        (ClientContactTest.ClientID = 7)
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
END
```

As I then run this via a VB.NET Front end the final stage is to give permissions to the Role (In my case called CRMObjects)

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE :: Certificate_Test2 TO CRMObjects;
GRANT CONTROL ON SYMMETRIC KEY :: SSN_Key_01 TO CRMObjects
```

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar,` with no length? If it's possible for that to ever be > 30 characters (symmetric keys aren't in my wheelhouse), but in general anyway, [always declare a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: To close the loop, was the certificate's private key not encrypted by a DMK before?

Comment: The certificate's private key had no prior encryption applied. My understanding is that 

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 WITH ALGORITHM = DES ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2 

is the operation that creates the private key and stores this somewhere in the Database system.

Later on I use this 
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Test2 to re-read the key and decrypt the data.

Comment: Aaron - I did some further testing on this and would confirm that a value MUST be used otherwise it truncates the data. I have updated the code. One point I would add is that the Table must be of a varbinary type (in this case I used varbinary(70) as encrypting the field does add around 40 - 50 characters. The only exception would be when the values is greater than 8000 and you must use MAX.